# Asynchronous url call in java server page

Tags: jsp, asynchronous, call

I have problem related to calling url into Java Server Page.
I want do this:
-on page load i want invoke example URL, without redirect current page.

How can I do it? I tried invoke java script function but i get acces denied(cross site scriptig).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use jsop , i never used it but i know jsonp works on cross domain requests